# How can I create a Vision Pro project with CocoaPods?

Tags: cocoapods, visionos

When I create a Vision Pro project using CocoaPods, the build fails with "Framework 'Pods_XXXX(Project NAME)' not found"

```
platform :ios, '15.0'

target 'XXXXX(MyProjectName)' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for XXXXX(MyProjectName)

end
```

Does the Vision Pro project not support CocoaPods or does the compilation fail because I am using the Vision Pro simulator?

I've searched the web for relevant content.

Comment: Did you run `pod install`? Did you open the workspace file instead of the project file in Xcode?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, CocoaPods are not yet natively supporting `visionOS`.  While `visionOS` has capability to run iOS/iPadOS apps, Xcode sees `visionOS` as its own operating system, and doesn't interpret iOS/iPadOS Pods as being compatible with `visionOS`.

There is a [now-merged pull request](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11961) in the CocoaPods repo that adds `visionOS` support to CocoaPods, but it's worth noting (at least at the time of this writing) that that pull request has not been released in a new CocoaPods version, so if it's something you want to leverage, you'll need to directly target the merged pull request's changes in a custom CocoaPods installation.  There is some guidance [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11961#issuecomment-1629709066) on how to do that (effectively using Bundler to target a CocoaPods commit, instead of the publicly released CocoaPods version).

It's further worth noting that a Podfile can only target one operating system per app target, which effectively means that if your app target is targeting iOS/iPadOS *and* visionOS, the Podifle is not going to work.  I've been successful in getting this to work by creating a new app target in Xcode (File -> New -> Target -> visionOS -> App) that builds for visionOS directly, and not a target that builds for iOS/iPadOS *and* visionOS.

TLDR; It seems like CocoaPods is not natively compatible with visionOS yet, and there may be a number of hurdles to overcome with getting an app that uses CocoaPods to build on visionOS natively.  This is a great time to consider Swift Package Manager (if that's practical for you) to negate this, but given the newness of visionOS, more work seems to need to be done to handle CocoaPods on visionOS (since every Pod likely only references iOS/iPadOS, and not visionOS, itself).

Answer (score 0):

you have to upgrade to CocoaPods 1.15.0 minimum, and add this at the bottom of your podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS'] = 'iphoneos iphonesimulator xros xrsimulator' # Includes VisionOS + xr simulator
      config.build_settings['TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY'] = '1,2,6,7' # '7' for VisionOS and 1 for iPhone, 2 for iPad, 6 for Mac
    end
  end
end
```