# Getting errors 'Module not found' compiling Apple Vision Pro SDK with Xcode 15 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, vision-pro

Using Xcode 15 beta 4/5/6 and `Cocoapods` for xcode workspace, when I was compiling the project with `Apple Vision Pro SDK` (not the one that designed for iPad, which was succeed though), get some errors, and the first one is like the following:

```
Module 'xxx' not found
```

[image: module not found error]
I was wondering if anyone has met this, I was told that it was possible `cocoapods` hasn't support `Apple Vision Pro SDK` yet which was not confirmed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a Vision Pro project with CocoaPods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76824630/how-can-i-create-a-vision-pro-project-with-cocoapods)

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a method to integrate VisionOS support into an iOS project, which I've tested personally. This approach helps navigate around two key limitations:

1. **Limited Pod Compatibility**: Many CocoaPods are not yet compatible with VisionOS due to code incompatibilities or outdated podspecs.
2. **Target Platform Restrictions in Podfiles**: CocoaPods doesn't currently support multiple platforms per target, requiring the duplication of your iOS target for VisionOS.

#### Steps for Integration:

##### 1. Add VisionOS as a Manual Target

Manually add VisionOS as a target in your Xcode project.

##### 2. Modify the Podfile for VisionOS

Keep the `platform :ios` in your Podfile, but add a `post_install` script to enable VisionOS for all Pods:

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      # Activate VisionOS support for all Pods
      config.build_settings['SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS'] = 'iphoneos iphonesimulator xros xrsimulator' # Include VisionOS (xros) and its simulator (xrsimulator)
      config.build_settings['TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY'] = '1,2,7' # Add the 7 device family
    end
  end
end
```

##### 3. Build and Identify Issues

Attempt to build your project and note any Pods that fail. For failing Pods, you might need to:

- Check for an (unreleased) update from the source.
- Modify the code to be VisionOS-compatible. Often, this involves:

  - Excluding incompatible code (`#if !os(visionOS)` or `#if os(iOS)`).
  - Adding availability checks (`if #available(iOS 10, visionOS 1, *)`).
  - Replacing `UIScreen` usages, like using `1` instead of `UIScreen.main.scale`, or `UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.keyWindow }.last?.bounds.size` instead of `UIScreen.main.bounds.size`.

##### 4. Contribute Back and Use Modified Forks

Send changes back to the original projects and, in the meantime, point to your modified fork in your Podfile:

```rb
pod 'Toast-Swift', git: 'https://github.com/codelathe/Toast-Swift.git', branch: 'initial_visionOS_support' # VisionOS-compatible fork of Toast-Swift
```

#### Conclusion

These steps should enable you to integrate VisionOS support into your project. For more details and ongoing discussions about CocoaPods' VisionOS support, you can refer to the [CocoaPods GitHub issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12094).